# Xcode autocomplete does not show STL header files without .h file ending

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm working with C++ in Xcode 12.5.1. Suddenly Xcode stopped showing me autocomplete for including typical STL header files such as chrono, algorithm or string. I still get autocomplete for includes with `.h` file endings like `math.h` but not `cmath` although both reside in the same directory. It's also not dependent on a specific project, it stopped working everywhere.
[image]

It previously worked without issues and as far as I know I didn't change anything. The only thing I could imagine, is that I downloaded the Xcode 13 beta but haven't opened it before that happened.

I already deleted everything in the `Derived Data` dir, updated and reinstalled Xcode (both from App Store and download from developer portal).

Any suggestions what causes the problem or what I could do to fix this?

Comment: `cmath` is spelled `cmath` not `math`...

Comment: oh well it also proposes `tgmath.h`. well, thanks for that very sarcastic comment